# How to find the most recent date for the previous category in DAX?

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am looking to create calculated column/s that will achieve the following goal: I need to calculate the maximum date for a previous episode of care (see data below). I am able to use the earlier() function to get the maximum date for the first and last episode of care, but I need it to be the previous episode rather than just the first or last. I am using calculated columns rather than measures because I need person-level data and need to do further calculations.

This is my desired outcome:

[image: desired outcome]

What I am able to achieve using earlier() function:

[image: ![wrong answer]

When a person has more than two episodes is where my formulas stop working. My formulas are similar to this:

earliest date = calculate(min([date]), filter(table, [person] = earlier([person]))

I've looked on the internet and similar questions but haven't found an example that worked. Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to filter for previous episode too.

```
MaxDatePrevEpisode =
CALCULATE (
    MAX ( Table1[date] ),
    ALLEXCEPT ( Table1, Table1[Person] ),
    Table1[episode] < EARLIER ( Table1[episode] )
)
```

This finds that last date in the table where the person matches and the episode is strictly less than the one for the current row. `ALLEXCEPT` removes any filtering on the episode and date columns (but keeps the person context).

Comment: Thank you so much! I had made a concatenated column and used that but didn't try using two filters.